# Are all objects(types) series? Can it be a constant?

Tags: object, types, pine-script, series, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5
indicator("tickerid", overlay = true)

closevalue(tickerid) =>
    sec = request.security(tickerid, '60', close)

type security_type
    string ticker

var security_type mysecurity = security_type.new(syminfo.tickerid)

plot(closevalue(syminfo.tickerid))
plot(closevalue(mysecurity.ticker))
```

This really simple indicator gives the following error for the second plot:

> Cannot call '#f0' with argument 'tickerid'='mysecurity.ticker'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected.

Even though I declared mysecurity as a constant var it still says it's a series?

How can I create a constant object(type) instead of it being a series?

I would expect it to work correctly if I declare mysecurity as a var but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript there is no way to change a serie to a constant variable.
As request.security must be used with a constant variable, you can't use standard variable (= series).
It is a one of the most strange limitation on pinescript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes you are right, that's why I was wondering if it was possible to have a custom type(object) that is not a series? But I guess not

Comment: I have seen people converting a series/array of UDT using str.format and json conversion. However, I wasn't able to understand whats happening there.

See e.g. https://www.tradingview.com/script/6pfVVhaZ-lib-plot-objects/ and find tostring method. Maybe you or someone else can make sense of it and share an easy example on how to convert a series of strings as part of an UDT to a simple string - since I am having the same challenge.